# How to compare two string and return result based on alphabet

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I've these two functions:

```
string BST::getVP (VoidPtr vp) const
{
    return *(static_cast <string *> (vp));
}

int BST::compare (VoidPtr vp1, VoidPtr vp2) const
{
    if (strcmp(getVP (vp1).c_str() , getVP (vp2).c_str()) == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (strcmp(getVP (vp1).c_str() , getVP (vp2).c_str()) != 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 2;
}
```

Currently if the two strings are the same, it'll return 1 and 0 if two strings are different. How can I return the same result but based on alphabet?

So for example:

- `vp1` is `apple` and `vp2` is `orange` then it return 0
- `vp1` is `orange` and `vp2` is `apple` then it return 2

Comment: How do you store strings? Do you use `std::string`?

Comment: `vp1` is apple and `vp2` is apple you return ?